# Novel with a women editing 20/21st century movies to add interaction and 3D effects

Tags: story-identification, novel

Novel with a women editing 20/21st century movies to add interaction and 3D effects.

She lived in a shack in the wilderness and if I remember correctly it was an additional source of income.

I thought it was in CUSP by Robert A Metzger, but I've just finished a re-read and it wasn't that book.

Been bugging me for weeks, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly *Remake* by Connie Willis? I don't recall the shack in the wilderness, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 'Earth' by David Brin.  One of  the characters was a female eco-terrorist who made a living re-editing 20th century movies to the standards of the 2050's.  At one point she was editing "Terminator" down to a shorter runtime so it would hold audience's attention.

Comment: Are you talking about Daisy?  Really, that's the _last_ thing I'd think of when I recall her character.  The dragon a bit moreso... :)  It would be great if you could find a quote from the book that talks about this.